# representing an XML config file with an IXmlSerializable class

Tags: c#, configuration, properties, xml-serialization, ixmlserializable

I'm writing in C# and trying to represent an XML config file through an `IXmlSerializable` class.  I'm unsure how to represent the nested elements in my config file, though, such as `logLevel`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <logging>
    <logLevel>Error</logLevel>
  </logging>
  <credentials>
    <user>user123</user>
    <host>localhost</host>
    <password>pass123</password>
  </credentials>
  <credentials>
    <user>user456</user>
    <host>my.other.domain.com</host>
    <password>pass456</password>
  </credentials>
</configuration>
```

There is an enum called `LogLevel` that represents all the possible values for the `logLevel` tag.  The tags within `credentials` should all come out as strings.  In my class, called `DLLConfigFile`, I had the following:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName="logLevel", DataType="LogLevel")]
public LogLevel LogLevel;
```

However, this isn't going to work because `<logLevel>` isn't within the root node of the XML file, it's one node deeper in `<logging>`.  How do I go about doing this?

As for the `<credentials>` nodes, my guess is I will need a second class, say `CredentialsSection`, and have a property such as the following:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName="credentials", DataType="CredentialsSection")]
public CredentialsSection[] AllCredentials;
```

**Edit:**  okay, I tried Robert Love's suggestion and created a `LoggingSection` class.  However, my test fails:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DLLConfigFile));

using (var stream = new FileStream(_configPath, FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(streamReader);
        var file = (DLLConfigFile)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        Assert.IsNotNull(file);
        LoggingSection logging = file.Logging;
        Assert.IsNotNull(logging); // fails here
        LogLevel logLevel = logging.LogLevel;
        Assert.IsNotNull(logLevel);
        Assert.AreEqual(EXPECTED_LOG_LEVEL, logLevel);
    }
}
```

The config file I'm testing with definitely has `<logging>`.  Here's what the classes look like:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("logging")]
public class LoggingSection : IXmlSerializable
{
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName="logLevel", DataType="LogLevel")]
    public LogLevel LogLevel;

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        LogLevel = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel),
            reader.ReadString());
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(Enum.GetName(typeof(LogLevel), LogLevel));
    }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class DLLConfigFile : IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="logging", DataType="LoggingSection")]
    public LoggingSection Logging;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass that has a single property `LogLevel` and then create a logging property on your base class that is of the the new type.

Comment: I tried something like this.  Should the new `LoggingSection` class implement `IXmlSerializable`, or can it just define `XmlRoot`, etc. attributes as necessary?

Comment: This worked.  I had to define `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` to do something specific for the log level in `LoggingSection`, and then make `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` in `DLLConfigFile` make use of `LoggingSection`'s `ReadXml` and `WriteXml`.